# How to make a custom sized poster?

Tags: posters, sciposter

I am trying to make a 36 x 36 poster, but the dimensions are not coming out correctly. I have tried

```
\documentclass[size=custom,width=91.44,height=91.44]{sciposter}

.
.
.

\renewcommand{\papertype}{custom} \renewcommand{\fontpointsize}{25pt}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{91.44cm} \setlength{\paperheight}{91.44cm}
```

but only the height is 36 in.

Comment: Did you try to use `geometry` package?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Without a full, compilable MWE we are very unlikely to be able to answer here. It would also be useful to know how you are compiling.